# I would like to share a Docker folder of a container and pointing to another shared folder

Tags: docker

I have a Docker with a few containers. I want share a folder of a container and pointing to another shared folder created locally in my machine.
This means, when I access to my locally shared folder I see the files of the folder container.

I have a folder "ShareFolder" on docker, this folder needs to point to a local share folder, to see the files in /home of the container.

Comment: On-host volumes tend to work the other way, which is they expose your on-hold folder to your container. You've not given any details about the problem you're trying to solve, but perhaps you could share an empty folder on your host to your container, and then the container copies files into it? Do you expect the files in the container change over time?

Comment: The files in the container are changing every day. How can I do the "share an empty folder on your host to your container , and then the container copies files into it" ?

Comment: Well, there's a couple of ways. If a periodic snapshot is OK, then a cron inside the container to Rsync or copy files from the source folder to the volume folder would work. If you want them to be live, then perhaps you could install a NFS server in the container, and then connect to that server using your host operating system.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: No worries. Note that the NFS server could cause some problems, depending on what things are writing to the files, and whether file handles are kept open over long periods. For example if they are raw database server files, be very careful, test thoroughly, and ensure that you have some sort of backup strategy if the data is valuable. Avoiding data corruption when files are contended between different readers/writers is not uniquely a Docker problem.